# Adding dynamic controls to form with auto scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, scroll

When I add my controls to the form, it goes fine until I try to specify a location larger than int16.MaxValue.  The controls just pile up on top of each other.  Here is code which is simplified but demonstrates the behavior:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AutoScroll = true;
    int nexttop = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        TextBox t  = new TextBox();
        t.Text = i.ToString();
        t.Multiline = true;
        if (nexttop > Int16.MaxValue)
        {
            bool debug = true;
        }
        t.Location = new Point(0, nexttop);
        t.Size = new Size(100, 77);
        nexttop += t.Height;
        this.Controls.Add(t);
    }
}
```

I want to avoid moving the scroll bar programaticaly, since this causes timing issues.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?  TIA.

Comment: I run your code and seems to work fine. What is the problem?

Comment: If you scroll down to the bottom, only 425 text boxes are visible.  Ya, I would expect at least an exception when I overflow the int.MinValue.

Comment: But I see 499 on the last textbox :(

Comment: I'm running Windows7 64-bit.  Serge says there are different behaviors - what are you running?

Comment: What does this have to do with `Int16.MaxValue`?

Comment: Ya, when I run the app on a virtual machine (XP 32bit) I get all of the text boxes, so it must be new behavior in Windows 7.

Comment: No matter what platforms it does or doesn't work on, instantiating so many text boxes is not very good programming practice. You should build some type of paging or dynamic scrolling capabilities into your UI and/or paint a list and only place text boxes when editing a particular record or something.

Comment: This was just a simplified example of what I am actually doing but I will consider paging as a possible solution.  Textbox was just a normal control to use that I could size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limit (32767) is due to GDI+. I believe different behaviours may be observed according to the Windows version.